rosdep keys command do not work on docker images osrf/ros:jazzy-desktop-full
I downloaded 2 docker images osrf/ros:jazzy-desktop and osrf/ros:jazzy-desktop-full
When trying to use rosdeps keys, it throws an error:
For example on rviz2:
rosdep keys rviz2

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource rviz2

I found a workaround to be adding ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to the distro, where the previous command then works
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/jazzy

Can I check if I am missing anything with the installation? 
I see that the issue has been resolved based on https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/660  but I still had to add ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
Thank you.
